# Get GPS Coordinates using Google Map VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

I am trying to get GPS Coordinates using Google Map in VB.net
but the code is not working

```
   Dim url As String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + FlatTextBox1.Text + "&sensor=false"
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Using response As WebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim dsResult As New DataSet()
            dsResult.ReadXml(reader)
            Dim dtCoordinates As New DataTable()
            dtCoordinates.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(3) {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Address", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Latitude", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Longitude", GetType(String))})
            For Each row As DataRow In dsResult.Tables("result").Rows
                Dim geometry_id As String = dsResult.Tables("geometry").[Select]("result_id = " + row("result_id").ToString())(0)("geometry_id").ToString()
                Dim location As DataRow = dsResult.Tables("location").[Select](Convert.ToString("geometry_id = ") & geometry_id)(0)
                dtCoordinates.Rows.Add(row("result_id"), row("formatted_address"), location("lat"), location("lng"))
            Next
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dtCoordinates
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: what is your error ? Do you use a api key ? (otherwise you'll get quota errors with this call...)

Comment: Nah i am not using API

Comment: I am getting kinda Syntex Error

Comment: you'll have to give us the exact error you get ;)